# Cannot join AD domain managed by QNAP NAS

Tags: active-directory, qnap

On my small network, I setted up a QNAP TS-473 running 4.5.1.1.540 as a Domain Controller for active directory.

I tried to join the domain from multiple Windows 10 Pro PCs but I always get an error saying the semaphore timeout period has expired.

I configured DNS correctly on both PCs, pointing to the NAS IP and the Domain Controller is found without any problem.

Comment: Do you have any firewall enabled, either on QNAP, or between QNAP and the client PCs?